# Sort huge dictionary of dictionaries by nested value efficiently?

Tags: python

How can I sort a dictionary like this (simplified version):

```
x = {
    '1': {
        'type': 'a',
        'created_at': 'date time object here',
    },
    '2': {
        'type': 'b',
        'created_at': 'date time object here',
    },
    '3': {
        'type': 'a',
        'created_at': 'date time object here',
    },
}
```

I have a dictionary with structure like above with several hundred thousands keys, I need to sort it by created_at value, which is a date time object.

Comment: And what is the expected output? A list of `(key, nested_dictionary)` tuples?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, ideally I would like the same dictionary as on input, just with reordered sub dictionaries. But I see that's not possible easily.

Comment: Dictionaries have no ordering. I do see your keys, as posted here, form a sequence. Perhaps a list would have been better here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually my keys are natural (mix of UUIDs and unique ids from third party systems such as Stripe, Gocardless etc). But I think the solution you posted will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a simple `key` function:

```
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1]['created_at'])
```

This produces a sorted list of `(key, nested_dict)` tuples, sorted on the `'created_at'` key of the nested dictionaries.

In Python 3, replace `iteritems()` with `items()`. You cannot avoid creating a list; sorting requires an orderable, mutable sequence to move the items around in.

Comment: I think it is important to make it explicit that this does not return a sorted dictionary because it is impossible to sort a dictionary.

Comment: @SethMMorton: You could pass the `sorted()` result to a `OrderedDict` object, but *usually* that's not needed anyway. But yeah, `dict` objects have no ordering.

Comment: I agree, an `OrderedDict` could work, but whenever I see someone use the phrase "How can I sort a dictionary" I want to make sure they understand that taken literally the request is impossible.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Hence my query on the question (about expected output), but the OP has gone radiosilent.